# P: TDA | PUNTEROS y MEMORIA

Tags: c

alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error que tengo? básicamente no me carga los "cartones"/matrices bien, adjunto los archivos .c y .h.
en resumen lo que tengo que hacer es cargar 3 matrices pero primero tengo que acceder a la estructura *Jugador* para posteriormente acceder a *cartonJugador* que es un puntero que apunta a una estructura llamada *Carton* que vendría a ser donde se encuentra la matriz.

PD: lo que tengo hasta ahora compila 2 matrices pero la segunda es pura basura, solo compila bien la primera matriz y luego se queda cargando como si estuviera en un bucle infinito
¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este big error? pd estoy aprendiendo

pd: en el main solo compilo algo();

```
//prueba.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "prueba.h"
#include "cartonnn.h"


struct Jugador {

    Carton cartonJugador[3];
    Carton cartonMaquina[3];

};
datos algo(){
    datos player = malloc(sizeof(struct Jugador));

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
player->cartonJugador[3] = cargarMatrizManual();

}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
mostrarMatriz(getCartonJugador(player->cartonJugador,i));
}

}
int getCartonJugador(datos x,int i){
return getBingo(x->cartonJugador[i]);
}
```

---

```
//prueba.h
struct Jugador;

typedef struct Jugador *datos;

datos algo();
int getCartonJugador(datos x,int i);
```

---

```
//cartonnn.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "prueba.h"
#include "cartonnn.h"

struct CartonEstructura{


    int carton[RENGLONES][COLUMNAS];

};

int *getBingo(Carton x){
return x->carton;
}

Carton cargarMatrizManual(){
  Carton x = malloc(sizeof(struct CartonEstructura));

    for (int r = 0; r < RENGLONES; r++){
        for (int c=0; c < COLUMNAS; c++){
            x->carton[r][c] = rand()% 9;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

void mostrarMatriz(Carton x){
    printf("\n");

    for(int r=0;r<RENGLONES;r++){
        for(int c=0;c<COLUMNAS;c++){
            printf("[% .2d]",x->carton[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

```
//cartonnn.h

#define RENGLONES 3
#define COLUMNAS 5

struct CartonEstructura;
typedef struct CartonEstructura *Carton;

int *getBingo(Carton x);
void mostrarMatriz(Carton x);
Carton cargarMatrizManual();
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el mensaje de error?

Comment: Ese es el problema que tengo no hay ningún mensaje de error, el programa compila bien pero el error esta en que solo me muestra 2 matrices en vez de 3 y solo muestra bien la primera, la segunda la muestra como full basura y al terminar de mostrar la segunda se queda en un bucle infinito el programa y tarda un rato en terminar.

Comment: En `algo()` tienes un subindice clavado en 3.... y el for va con i de 0 a 2.... creo que deberías usar i como el subindice.